# Refrescar layout en pymel de forma automatica

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un plugin para Maya (programado en pymel), en el que necesito que mi panel me refresque automáticamente mi listado de objetos que tengo en la pantalla.

Lo tengo hecho con un botón que, cuando le doy, me refresca el listado de objetos, pero quiero que sea de manera automática:

He leído que estas lineas son las que lo hacen automáticamente (llaman a mi función `refreshPlugin`)

```
cmds.scriptJob(event=["DagObjectCreated", refreshPlugin], parent=(window))
cmds.scriptJob(event=["Undo",refreshPlugin], parent =(window))
cmds.scriptJob(event=["Redo",refreshPlugin], parent =(window))
cmds.scriptJob(event=["NameChanged", refreshPlugin], parent =(window))
```

Pero en lugar de volver a crearme un nuevo listado de objeto hacen que se me deje de mostrar todo. ¿Alguna idea de lo que me está fallando?